# Unity UI buttons are not being highlighted when the cursor hovers over them on the Quest 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, unity-ui, oculusquest, unity-xr

So I'm having an issue where Unity UI buttons are not being highlighted nor animated when the raycast is over them. It works fine in the Unity editor, but not when I build the apk to the quest 2. The clicks work fine, is when highlighted the problem.

I followed the steps on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zJw0F_3UZ0

I'm using the prefab UIHelpers. I believe the problem might be in the script "OVRInputModule" which is in the eventsystem that is a child of the UIHelpers game object.

[image: Canvas inspector]

[image: Eventsystem inspector]

If you have any idea, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After three days of searching for a solution, I finally found it. For anyone having the same issue, remove the script "OVR Scene Sample Controller" from your OVR Player Controller. I'm not sure what this script does that prevent the buttons from being highlighted... but yeah.